# While Loop variable assignment to Runnable

Tags: java, variables, runnable, final

Why does each Runnable print the same device when each one is supposed to be assigned a different device?

It seems like each Runnable is using the last device assigned from the while loop. How can I ensure that each Runnable is assigned one device from the loop?

```
Iterator<TaskCard> i = taskManager.getTaskCards().iterator();

while (i.hasNext()) {
    TaskCard taskCard = i.next();
    taskCard.updateTask();
    ReturnInterface<String> returnInterface = new TaskReturnIterface(taskManager, taskCard);
    Task task = taskCard.getTask();
    ProtocolInterface selectedProtocol = task.getDevice().getSelectedProtocol();
    selectedProtocol.setTask(task);
    selectedProtocol.setReturnInterface(returnInterface);

    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        final ProtocolInterface mySelectedProtocol=selectedProtocol;
        @Override
        public void run() {  
            System.out.println("[Taskmanager.TaskReturnInterface.actionPerformed.RUN()]selectedProtocol device= " + mySelectedProtocol.getDevice());
        }
    });

}
```

Below is the Protocol Interface code that wsa requested.

```
public abstract class ProtocolInterface<N> implements Callable<ReturnInterface<N>>, Serializable{

protected DefaultDevice device;
protected String name = "";
protected Task task;
protected Date scheduledDate;
protected ReturnInterface<N> returnInterface;

final private CredentialInterface credential = new CredentialInterface() {
    private String user = "";
    private String password = "";
    private int port = 22;

    @Override
    public String getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    @Override
    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    @Override
    public int getPort() {
        return port;
    }

    @Override
    public void setUser(String s) {
        user = s;
    }

    @Override
    public void setPassword(String s) {
        password = s;
    }

    @Override
    public void setPort(int p) {
        port = p;
    }

    @Override
    public DefaultDevice getHost() {
        return device;
    }

    @Override
    public void setHost(DefaultDevice host) {
        System.out.println("[ProtocolInterface].CredentialInterface.setHost() host= "+host);
        device = host;
    }
};

boolean useIP = true;

public ProtocolInterface() {
}

public CredentialInterface getCredential() {
    return credential;
}

public ProtocolInterface(String name, DefaultDevice device) {
    this.name = name;
    this.device = device;
}

public DefaultDevice getDevice() {
    return device;
}

public ReturnInterface<N> getReturnInterface() {
    return returnInterface;
}

public void setReturnInterface(ReturnInterface<N> returnInterface) {
    this.returnInterface = returnInterface;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public Task getTask() {
    return task;
}

public void setTask(Task task) {
    this.task = task;
}

public Date getScheduledDate() {
    return scheduledDate;
}

public void setScheduledDate(Date scheduledDate) {
    this.scheduledDate = scheduledDate;
}

public abstract Icon getIcon();

public abstract CredentialForm_Interface getCredentialForm();


@Override
public int hashCode() {
    int hash = 7;
    hash = 47 * hash + Objects.hashCode(this.device);
    hash = 47 * hash + Objects.hashCode(this.name);
    return hash;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj) {
        return true;
    }
    if (obj == null) {
        return false;
    }
    if (getClass() != obj.getClass()) {
        return false;
    }
    final ProtocolInterface<?> other = (ProtocolInterface<?>) obj;
    if (this.useIP != other.useIP) {
        return false;
    }
    if (!Objects.equals(this.name, other.name)) {
        return false;
    }
    if (!Objects.equals(this.device, other.device)) {
        return false;
    }
    if (!Objects.equals(this.credential, other.credential)) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}



@Override
public String toString() {
    return name;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you're right! You create `Runnable`instance with reference to the protocol object. This reference could be changed until `invokeLater` runt this task. So you have to copy required data instead of save reference.

```
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        final Device device = selectedProtocol.getDevice();
        @Override
        public void run() {  
            System.out.println("[Taskmanager.TaskReturnInterface.actionPerformed.RUN()]selectedProtocol device= " + device);
        }
    });
```

Comment: the output is still the same.

Comment: @JamieSnipes could you provide `Device` and `SelectedProtocol` class sources?

Comment: I'm assuming that since selectedProtocol also changes, this could be why it still is printing the same device.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Iterator<TaskCard> i = taskManager.getTaskCards().iterator();

while (i.hasNext()) {
    TaskCard taskCard = i.next();
    taskCard.updateTask();
    ReturnInterface<String> returnInterface = new TaskReturnIterface(taskManager, taskCard);
    Task task = taskCard.getTask();
    final ProtocolInterface selectedProtocol = task.getDevice().getSelectedProtocol();
    selectedProtocol.setTask(task);
    selectedProtocol.setReturnInterface(returnInterface);

    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {  
            System.out.println("[Taskmanager.TaskReturnInterface.actionPerformed.RUN()]selectedProtocol device= " + selectedProtocol.getDevice());
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to say without more information on `TaskCard` and other objects but you should try to declare some variable `final` and try to print the hash code for the object, to check if it really is the same *instance* or a different instances semantically equal:

```
for (Iterator<TaskCard> i = taskManager.getTaskCards().iterator(); i.hasNext();) {
    TaskCard taskCard = i.next();
    taskCard.updateTask();
    ReturnInterface<String> returnInterface = new TaskReturnIterface(taskManager, taskCard);
    Task task = taskCard.getTask();
    // Mark this as "final" so you can use it as is in any internal anonymous class:
    final ProtocolInterface selectedProtocol = task.getDevice().getSelectedProtocol();
    selectedProtocol.setTask(task);
    selectedProtocol.setReturnInterface(returnInterface);
    System.out.println("[1] selectedProtocol device=" + selectedProtocol.getDevice().hashCode());
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {  
            System.out.println("[2] selectedProtocol device=" + selectedProtocol.getDevice().hashCode());
        }
    });
}
```

It would seem there are some ties between objects that might either print the same output or use the same object in the backend. Especially this part:

```
ProtocolInterface selectedProtocol = task.getDevice().getSelectedProtocol();
selectedProtocol.setTask(task);
selectedProtocol.setReturnInterface(returnInterface);
```

looks strange as the `selectedProtocol` seems somehow tied to a device itself tied to a task, then you have to set its task again?

It basically is doing `task.getDevice().getSelectedProtocol().setTask(task)` which looks like there is some kind of loophole you should check...

Also, the `SwingUtilities.invokeLater()` is kind of reserved for GUI processing so you might want to remove that (unless it is doing GUI...).